# How do you seed images using Shrine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, shrine

I can't seed my images using shrine, unlike carrierwave the below code doesn't work.

```
Profile.create! id: 2,
                user_id: 2, 
                brand: "The Revengers", 
                location: "Azgaurd", 
                phone_number: "send a raven",
                image_data: File.open(Rails.root+"app/assets/images/seed/thor.png")
```

i've also tried

```
image_data: ImageUploader.new(:store).upload(File.open(Rails.root+"app/assets/images/seed/thor.png"))
```

but it returns

```
JSON::ParserError in Profiles#show
743: unexpected token at '#<ImageUploader::UploadedFile:0x007fd8bc3142e0>'
```

Is there a shrine way? I can't seem to find it anywhere.

shrine.rb

```
require "cloudinary"
require "shrine/storage/cloudinary"


Cloudinary.config(
  cloud_name: ENV['CLOUD_NAME'],
  api_key:ENV['API_KEY'],
  api_secret:ENV['API_SECRET'],
)

Shrine.storages = {
  cache: Shrine::Storage::Cloudinary.new(prefix: "cache"), # for direct 
uploads
  store: Shrine::Storage::Cloudinary.new(prefix: "store"),
}
```

profile.rb

```
class Profile < ApplicationRecord
  include ImageUploader[:image]
  belongs_to :user
  has_and_belongs_to_many :genres
  scoped_search on: [:brand]
end
```

image_uploader.rb

```
class ImageUploader < Shrine
end
```

Comment: Please share `Profile` class definition along with Shrine initializer and the `ImageUploader.rb`

Comment: Okay, I've added the extra information above.

Comment: do you get any error messages when you run the command?

Comment: Not when i run db:seed, but when i go to the profile it wont load the image.

743: unexpected token at '#<File:0x007f83204b7800>'

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Using `Shrine`, the attachment attribute (e.g. `image_data`) on the model (e.g. `Profile`) is a text column in the database (you can define it as `json` or `jsonb` too). Now it should be clear that this column cannot accept a `File` object (which you are trying to do).

First you need to use an uploader (e.g. `ImageUploader`) to upload the target file in one of your configured Shrine storages (e.g. `:cache` or `:store`):

```
uploader = ImageUploader.new(:store)
file = File.new(Rails.root.join('app/assets/images/seed/thor.png'))
uploaded_file = uploader.upload(file)
```

Here the main method of the uploader is `#upload`, which takes an IO-like object on the input, and returns a representation of the uploaded file (`ImageUploader::UploadedFile`) on the output.

At this point, you have the uploaded file in hand. Now the model (`Profile`) will only need the json representation of the uploaded file in its attachment attribute column (`image_data`) like so:

```
Profile.create! id: 2,
                user_id: 2, 
                brand: "The Revengers", 
                location: "Azgaurd", 
                phone_number: "send a raven",
                image_data: uploaded_file.to_json
```

Comment: Works! Beautiful!

Answer (score 0):

Updating this answer to work with the latest version of Shrine (3.4.0).

models/profile.rb

```
class Profile < ApplicationRecord
  #  image_data  :jsonb (in the database)

  # add an `image` virtual attribute managed by Shrine
  include ImageUploader::Attachment.new(:image)
end
```

In a rails console:

```
file = URI.open("https://picsum.photos/200/300")
profile = Profile.first
profile.image = file
profile.save
```

With that, the uploader uploads and processes the file as if it were uploaded in a form.